# Presto SQL + Athena: Cast date fail with error message: INVALID_FUNCTION_ARGUMENT

Tags: sql, date, amazon-athena

I have a table with `datehourminute` column with string datatype and formatted as `202012062302`. I want to select the date and cast it to date, so I made a query that looks like this:

```
select cast(date_parse(created_date, '%Y-%m-%d') as date) created_date,
daily_user
from 
(
    select concat(substr(datehourminute,1,4),'-',
        substr(datehourminute,5,2),'-',substr(datehourminute,7,2))
        as created_date, sum(users) as daily_user
    from "a-schema".a-table
    group by 1
)
order by 1;
```

However, that query returns this error:

> SQL Error [100071] [HY000]: [Simba]AthenaJDBC
>
> An error has been thrown from the AWS Athena client.
>
> INVALID_FUNCTION_ARGUMENT: Invalid format: "(oth-er-)"

Any idea how to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: If the table name contains a hyphen, you need to quote this as `"a-table"`. Is the SQL the one you're actually having problem with?